# Practice to end a speech with praying for moshiach

Tags: tefilla, minhag, messiah, speeches-addresses

Something I've noticed is almost every speech, *devar Torah*, or words of inspiration I hear end the exact same. The speaker ends with some permutation of the following words:

> May we all merit to see the coming of *moshiach*, speedily in our days, amen.

I have a very strong feeling this is a recent practice. I don't think in Europe people were ending their speeches this way.

What is the earliest recorded time that a speech ended this way, either in print or transcribed. Bonus points for a reasonable explanation for what triggered this change in practice.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.7.3

Comment: I have a hunch that one motive or support for this idea may have come from various Tanac"h references using the term *Mashiach* or similar, such as the end of Chana's "song" to God after Shmuel was born; the end of David's song thanking God for saving him from his enemies. So, there is some precedent to the concept. As for this theme in more modern times, probably the huge losses in the Holocaust became a major motive for praying for salvation and redemption via Mashiach.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Taanit.4.8

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.20

Comment: @DoubleAA None of those examples bring in the prayer randomly, though; it’s talking about the Beis HaMikdash anyway, so it includes a prayer for it. Another example is the end of Sotah for the coming of Mashiach. A lot of modern cases don’t discuss the Beis HaMikdash at all in the speech and end with a prayer for its rebuilding anyway.

Comment: Sounds like a beautiful, holy version of Cato's go-to speech closer https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est

Comment: Concluding a speech is often awkward. You finish the Devar Torah and now what? Silence? You say “I’m done”? “Thank you for listening”? The prayer for Moshiach is an easy way out of the jam.

Comment: "Recent"? IDK how you define that, but I've been hearing it for 50+ years.

Comment: @DannySchoemann less than 100 years old is very recent when it comes to Jewish history

Comment: " The prayer for Moshiach is an easy way out of the jam." It can seem that way, agreeably. But, I rarely mention the Moshiach when I give a D'var Torah. Perhaps, I'm in minority? At any rate, while it would seem nice to connect the Moshiach theme to the rest of the D'var Torah, it seems that's hard to do most of the time. So, there's nothing wrong with just ending things where you are. It seems, though, that many rabbanim want to end every D'var Torah on a "positive" note, and, perhaps hope for the coming of Moshiach is "positive"? That can be debated, too.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?lang=bi

The Mishna in *Avos 6:6* says

> שֶׁכָּל הָאוֹמֵר דָּבָר בְּשֵׁם אוֹמְרוֹ מֵבִיא גְאֻלָּה לָעוֹלָם

I have seen in the sefer לקוטי בתר לקוטי אבות חלק ב (circa 1951)

(hebrewbooks.org only has the first part https://www.hebrewbooks.org/4120
if anyone can find it and provide the exact *lashon* would be appreciated )

that perhaps this is the reason why we end a speech with a prayer for the *geulah*, in case the speaker inadvertently did not say something בשם אומרו, it may *ch'v* prolong the *galus*.

Comment: Thanks for the info but this doesn't answer my question